# How to run custom kernel and initrd in UEFI?

Tags: kernel, grub2, uefi, bios

I have a dev machine with BIOS and after compiling my kernel and initrd, I'm able to use it with a simple `menuentry`:

```
menuentry "mlinux" {
       linux /boot/mlinuz quiet
       initrd /boot/minitramfs
}
```

However running this on another machine with UEFI fails, I get:

```
error: kernel doesn't support EFI handover.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

I thought maybe this has to do with lack of support for UEFI in my kernel so I recompiled it with `EFI_STUB` support (had to enable `ACPI` too). Now I get a dark screen. If I add `echo` before each step and remove `quiet`, I'll see `echo` messages but nothing more, no kernel msg, nothing.

After seeing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586673/how-to-create-uefi-bootable-image-from-bzimage-custom-kernal) and this [post](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/efi-stub.html), I copied my kernel to:

- /boot/efi/mlinuz.efi
- /boot/efi/EFI/mlinuz.efi
- /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/mlinuz.efi

and have used theses addresses as my path in `menuentry`, still none of them work saying file can't be found. Where should I copy the file and what should be in my `menuentry`?

**Side question:** if I boot with my own linux kernel but the custom `initrd`, I can launch my program but can't interact with it using keyboard. Any idea why!?

**EDIT:** found about `linuxefi` and `initrdefi` but since it can't find the file, I drop to command line, use ls to find my hard and then use `linuxefi (hd0,pt2)/mlinuz64.efi` but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: This all hugely depends on your particular hardware, UEFI firmware and your actual kernel configuration. Side answer: it seems you don't either have a console driver or your application doesn't use console properly. This again depends on what console there is and how you are using it.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov what should I be looking into? how can I start debugging it, what to check, etc? re side answer: it works just fine on bios machine, on qemu, etc

Comment: There are quite a number of tunables. Start by properly describing: which hardware you have and which firmware is there. Say which related kernel CONFIG_* variables you configured and how. If that's GRUB, it should generally not bother whether your Linux supports EFI, because it runs it with via [multiboot spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiboot_specification), not UEFI. The EFI stub is only needed for booting Linux *without* a separate bootloader; in this case, it is wise to include initramfs and command line into kernel image file.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I'm using GRUB2 (Ubuntu) and it was asking for `EFI handover`, previously I had CONFIG of `EFI` & `EFI_STUB` enabled (which made error go away but showed blank screen) then saw [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EFIBootLoaders) and after enabling FRAMEBUFFER related confs, I can now see the output. I guess framebuffer was the issue and I only needed `CONFIG_EFI` and not even `CONFIG_EFI_STUB`?

Comment: EFI Framebuffer depends on EFI. If you plan to use Grub (or other bootloader) you may omit EFI Stub, which is only needed to load the kernel directly by the firmware without an additional bootloader.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thanks. What does Framebuffer exactly do and why is it needed? Also, I haven't enabled USB support for kernel, and on dev machine I can plug in usb keyboard but not on prod machine, I guess motherboard deals with that? Haven't had the chance to recompile with USB support and see if it'd finally work yet though.

Comment: "Framebuffer" is a frame buffer, a buffer in the memory which video card uses to take information from when it is going to display something. You write into the frame buffer, and this is precisely the way to output data. There are different interfaces: where in the memory, how the data is organized, and so on), so different frame buffers: [VGA text](https://wiki.osdev.org/Printing_To_Screen) (80x25 char array at 0xB8000), EFI, graphical frame buffers, etc. // Don't rely on "motherboard" or "bios". If you use something, provide drivers yourself.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into a blank screen as well, the problem was that I needed to enable FRAMEBUFFER:

```
CONFIG_FB_EFI=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
```

Turns out you can also disable `CONFIG_EFI_STUB` if you're using grub and not direct boot.