# Unable to boot Linux kernel directly through EFISTUB

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, virtualbox, uefi

I've compiled Linux kernel 5.18.4 from source, enabling all the EFI-related options, without any built-in parameters, nor a default init path, also, it's worth mentioning that i'm not making use of initramfs/initrd

I'm trying to boot this kernel through VirtualBox 6.1.34, on a VM with EFI support

The installation disk (`/dev/sda`) has two partitions:

- `/dev/sda1` a 512mb EFI system partition formatted as FAT32 mounted at `/boot`
- `/dev/sda2` a 15.5gb root partition formatted as ext4 mounted at `/`

The kernel is located at `/boot/EFI/BOOT/boox64.efi`, seems like this naming convention makes it boot automatically, skipping the UEFI shell, and removing the need for creating a boot entry through `efibootmgr`, but i'm not sure if that's the norm across different UEFI implementations on different hardware

Whenever i try to boot it, i get the following error:

[image: virtualbox uefi error]

On previous attempts, by making minor adjustments like changing the kernel path and doing some other tweaks, the result was similar, whenever i tried to execute `vmlinuz.efi` through the EFI shell, the machine would hang forever, without displaying a single error message (this is the case even when passing `root=/dev/sda2` and `init=/bin/init` as parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to enable framebuffer on kernel `.config` in order to prevent running into a blank screen:

```
CONFIG_FB_EFI=y
CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y
```

Thanks to [d9ngle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/350921/d9ngle) for his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708336)